# Identify the reason for MongoDB crash

Tags: mongodb

Our websites runs on Ubuntu 16.04 with MongoDB 3.6.3 . Today the mongodb server got crashed and I had to restart the server manually. I am not sure what can be the reason for this
The log shows no much information. Is there any way to identify what might have went wrong and how this fix this ?

```
2020-08-19T17:45:33.837+0000 I NETWORK  [conn11306] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:42722 conn: { driver: { name: "mongoc / ext-mongodb:PHP", version: "1.8.2 / 1.3.4" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Ubuntu", version: "18.04", architecture: "x86_64" }, platform: "cfg=0x2b8e9 posix=200809 stdc=201112 CC=GCC 7.3.0 CFLAGS="-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/php-mongodb-XOtnKb/php-mongodb-1.3.4=. -fstack-protector-st..." }
2020-08-19T17:45:34.422+0000 I COMMAND  [conn11306] command jothishi.jothishi command: find { find: "ukkca", filter: { user_id: 14495 }, $readPreference: { mode: "secondaryPreferred" }, $db: "jothishi" } planSummary: COLLSCAN keysExamined:0 docsExamined:17797 cursorExhausted:1 numYields:141 nreturned:0 reslen:105 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 284 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 142 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 142 } } } protocol:op_query 584ms
2020-08-19T17:45:42.764+0000 I NETWORK  [conn11306] end connection 127.0.0.1:42722 (0 connections now open)
2020-08-19T17:45:54.656+0000 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:42798 #11307 (1 connection now open)
2020-08-19T17:45:54.657+0000 I NETWORK  [conn11307] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:42798 conn: { driver: { name: "mongoc / ext-mongodb:PHP", version: "1.8.2 / 1.3.4" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Ubuntu", version: "18.04", architecture: "x86_64" }, platform: "cfg=0x2b8e9 posix=200809 stdc=201112 CC=GCC 7.3.0 CFLAGS="-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/php-mongodb-XOtnKb/php-mongodb-1.3.4=. -fstack-protector-st..." }
2020-08-19T17:45:57.778+0000 I NETWORK  [conn11307] end connection 127.0.0.1:42798 (0 connections now open)
2020-08-19T17:46:43.364+0000 I COMMAND  [ftdc] serverStatus was very slow: { after basic: 0, after asserts: 919, after backgroundFlushing: 919, after connections: 919, after dur: 919, after extra_info: 919, after globalLock: 931, after locks: 931, after logicalSessionRecordCache: 931, after network: 941, after opLatencies: 941, after opcounters: 941, after opcountersRepl: 941, after repl: 941, after security: 941, after storageEngine: 951, after tcmalloc: 951, after transactions: 951, after wiredTiger: 963, at end: 1232 }
```

---

```
2020-08-21T04:21:45.518+0000 I CONTROL  [main] ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
2020-08-21T04:21:45.549+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=17877 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb 64-bit host=ukkca.com
2020-08-21T04:21:45.549+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.6.3
2020-08-21T04:21:45.549+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 9586e557d54ef70f9ca4b43c26892cd55257e1a5
2020-08-21T04:21:45.549+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
2020-08-21T04:21:45.549+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2020-08-21T04:21:45.549+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2020-08-21T04:21:45.549+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2020-08-21T04:21:45.549+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2020-08-21T04:21:45.549+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2020-08-21T04:21:45.550+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongodb.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1", unixDomainSocket: { pathPrefix: "/run/mongodb" } }, storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongodb", journal: { enabled: true } }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log" } }
2020-08-21T04:21:45.550+0000 W -        [initandlisten] Detected unclean shutdown - /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock is not empty.
2020-08-21T04:21:45.554+0000 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /var/lib/mongodb created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2020-08-21T04:21:45.554+0000 W STORAGE  [initandlisten] Recovering data from the last clean checkpoint.
2020-08-21T04:21:45.554+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] 
2020-08-21T04:21:45.554+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine
2020-08-21T04:21:45.554+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
```

Comment: Those log messages show what happened after the node was restarted.  If you want to find out why it crashed, you need to look at what happened before that.

Comment: @Joe, I have updated the logs prior to restart.

Comment: If there were no log entries between `2020-08-19T17:46:43.364+0000` and `2020-08-21T04:21:45.518+0000` that might have been OOM kill, or something sending a signal 9.  Syslog or dmesg may be able to shed some light on that.

Comment: Got the response - Thank you @Joe!
[Wed Aug 19 17:48:13 2020] Out of memory: Kill process 18094 (mongod) score 218 or sacrifice child
[Wed Aug 19 17:48:13 2020] Killed process 18094 (mongod) total-vm:1604060kB, anon-rss:445356kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
[Wed Aug 19 17:48:13 2020] oom_reaper: reaped process 18094 (mongod), now anon-rss:0kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB